# No module named 'flask_security' in my Flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, flask-security

The app.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, url_for, redirect, render_template, request, abort
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, \
    UserMixin, RoleMixin, login_required, current_user
from flask_security.utils import encrypt_password
import flask_admin
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_admin import helpers as admin_helpers
from flask_admin import BaseView, expose
from wtforms import PasswordField
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Flask\Admin login app\Flask-Admin-Dashboard\app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_security'
```

I Have already installed Flask_ Security Through pip install but it still shows this error. I am using python version 3.10.2 and these are all the requirements that are installed in my virtual env :

```
Babel==2.10.3
blinker==1.5
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.5
dnspython==2.2.1
email-validator==1.2.1
enum34==1.1.6
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-Admin==1.6.0
Flask-BabelEx==0.9.4
Flask-Login==0.6.2
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-Security==3.0.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==1.0.1
greenlet==1.1.3
idna==3.3
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
passlib==1.7.4
pytz==2022.2.1
speaklater==1.3
SQLAlchemy==1.4.40
Werkzeug==2.2.2
WTForms==3.0.1
```

Comment: This should work. Is your virtual environment activated? What does pip freeze say?

Comment: yes my virtual environment is activated pip freeze works normal

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using VS code